# Creating a PDF file that prevents saving background images

Tags: linux, pdf

I would like to create a PDF file such that the viewer is able to select and copy the text, but not the images in it.

I have seen examples of this in some invoicing documents, where you cannot actually select and then save the logo printed in it. Hovering with the mouse pointer above the image does not lead to options for further action.

In contrast, if I compose a document having text and figures with Libre Office, for example, the resulting PDF file recognizes an embedded object and gives the possibility to save the image. This is the feature that I would like to prevent. Say that I would like to 'flatten' the images on the background.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Just a thought, try making the image a watermark.

Comment: Adding a watermark with Libre Office (Format > Page > Background > As graphic) introduces an image that can be saved out from the PDF with mouse action. Additionally, this option is much less flexible than ordinary placing any image in the background, since the watermark can be only anchored at fixed points in the page. Note that my question is not restricted to Libre Office though.

Comment: You might find this thread enlightening: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40739/embedded-pdf-images-in-pdf-output-not-selectable-cant-be-copied

Comment: Thanks. That discussion aims to the opposite problem, that is to make images downloadable from the PDF, while I want to prevent this. However, I have checked some PDFs that I created with LaTeX and both vector (pdf) and raster (png) images embedded in the document are downloadable from the PDF. The raster/vector distinction is made in that discussion, whereby I did not experience that other issue in the first place. Therefore, I am still looking for the tools and operations, prior to or on the PDF document, that flatten the image content against the background.

Comment: Another point made in that thread is that even if an image isn't selectable, it could still be captured in a screen snapshot.  Also, different pdf tools vary in their features and capabilities, so you might find a way to make the image non-selectable in one program, but it might be selectable in another.  The nature of the unselectable logo may be that it's locked or protected, and whether that setting is honored may depend on the pdf software used.  But if your goal is just to duplicate the nature of those logos, somebody must know how it's done because it's been done.

Comment: Concur. I am hopeful that an explanation and guidance will come up regarding Linux or platform-independent, open-source tools.